# How can I Retrieve only a Row from a table in Laravel

Tags: php

I am new in laravel and i am developing an application that I  need to display the persons first and last name upon registering on my system. But I am finding it it hard to achieve this  instead my code retrieves all the first and last names from my  table if i use the instance $contact =contacts::all();

My table named contact has fields like fname, lname,email,phone, body, updated_at,...

I have tried using the ...all()->pluck() to select only the first name and last name but my views displays everything first and last name from the table. I can do it in my views but i need your help in my controller.

Here is my controller

```
$contact =contacts::all()->pluck('lname','fname').
```

Anyone with an idea please

Comment: All() gets all of the rows. You'll want to use [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses) clauses to find the exact record.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the where() function please. What arguments I am suppose to pass? In my case, I want to retrieve the first name as fname and last name as lname

Answer (score 1):

-> contacts::all() --- This will result all the data in contacts model

-> contacts::first() --- This will result only single row. please add a where condition with this for required result. 
e.g contacts::where('name','=','abc')->first();

Comment: Oooh thanks. It seem to be working in the controller but now i get the error that says invalid argument in foreach. Here is my view.
@foreach($contact as $contact)
<tr>
        <th> {{$contact->lname}}</th>
   </tr>
    @endforeach

Comment: $contacts = contacts::where('name','=','abc')->first();

After getting the data with the condition , you have to pass data from controller to view.
You can pass data to view by using "with" or "contact" methods.
return View::make("routename", compact('contacts')); OR
return View::make("routename")->with(array('contact'=>$contacts));

Answer (score 0):

`contacts::all()` will retrieve every single row. If you want to limit the selection to contacts that only have a certain first/last name, then you'll want to use `where` and `get()`, which will only get those particular rows:

```
$fname = 'John';
$lname = 'Doe';
contacts::where('fname', $fname)->where('lname', $lname)->get();
```

The two variables, of course, would be populated with whatever you're looking for. You can also pass in a comparison as the second parameter, in case you want to check for not equals, LIKE (good for case insensitive searches or wildcard searches), or greater than/less than for numbers and dates.

```
contacts::where('fname', '=', $fname)->where('lname','=', $lname)->get();
```

Note that this will bring up everyone with the name John | Doe. It may not be the person who just registered. For that, you'll want to save the user ID somewhere such as in the session after they register, and instead look for that id, which will bring up only 1 record instead of a collection of records that `get()` would provide.

```
contacts::find($id);
```